# What is a good practice to store refresh and access tokens in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am using next.js and so far I want to avoid suing a database in my app.
What is the best practice to persist an API refresh token that I need to update occasionally?
It can’t be in .env sine it can change.

Comment: An alternative to a database is the file system.

Comment: If it's all servers-side, just store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens can to stored in a cookie

if token value stored in cookie is an important value you can consider session

or try to delete cookie when your page unmounts